# How to display and group posts?

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to download all Wordpress posts that have the right taxonomy and terms. I have some problem getting the result.

I want it to look like this:

```
**Opel Astra**

Opel Astra I [1992-1995]

Opel Astra II [1995-2000]

**Opel Vectra**

Opel Vectra I [1992-1995]

Opel Vectra II [1995-2000]
```

My Code:

```
$args = array(
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'marka',
            'terms' => array( 'opel' )
        ),
    ),
    'post_type' => 'auto'
);
$loop = new WP_Query($args);
     if($loop->have_posts()) {
    $term = $wp_query->queried_object;
     while($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();  

        $title = get_the_title();
        echo $title;
   echo '<li><a href="'.get_permalink().'">'.get_the_title().'</a></li>';
      endwhile;
}
```

Currently receiving the result:

```
**Opel Astra I**
Opel Astra I [1992-1995]

**Opel Astra II**
Opel Astra II [1995-2000]
```

Comment: I showed above what the result is.

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? How does the given code generate the output you've provided?